# Adding an overlaid line on video footage following the center of the frames via video processing/pattern recognition

Tags: opencv, overlay, video-processing, pattern-recognition

I have multiple 1-minute videos taken outside (a building, a sea cliff, etc). The camera is not fixed, it's taken by a drone very slowly going up a cliff for example.

What I need to do, if even possible, is use OpenCV or other video processing framework to automatically add a path to each of those video, a red line. 
The red line would follow the location pointed by the centre of the video frame.

It means that on each frame, I must find the locations pointed at on the previous/next frames via some sort of pattern recognition and somehow  link them with an overlaid red line path.

Is there some sort of algorithm or tool that facilitate this process? How would you approach this problem?

Example:

From those frames:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

`*
*
*
*`

To those frames:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

(in the real, slow, footage, the consecutive frames would be much closer to each other)

Looks like for all frames, I must try to locate all the previous/next frames and link their centres as an rightly ordered line. Surely, that must have been done before?

Comment: some sort of image/panorama stitching applied to frames?

Comment: You would have to first note down the central pixel of the first frame in each video. Then track that pixel using some feature detector like SIFT or SURF.

Comment: Did u achieve anything?